# Algorithm for importing GIFT format questions in Moodle

Tags: database, moodle

I am trying to locate the script (the code) for importing questions in the GIFT format in Moodle.

I would appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head: question/format/gift

https://github.com/moodle/moodle/tree/master/question/format/gift